# Error on all Program.cs files on eShopOnContainers, microsoft microsevice based implmentation

Tags: microservices, .net-5

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0260 Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Program'; another partial declaration of this type exists WebStatus D:\GitHub\eShopOnContainers\src\Web\WebStatus\Program.cs 123 Active

...
(int httpPort, int grpcPort) GetDefinedPorts(IConfiguration config)
{
var grpcPort = config.GetValue("GRPC_PORT", 5001);
var port = config.GetValue("PORT", 80);
return (port, grpcPort);
}

```
public class Program
{
    public static string Namespace = typeof(Startup).Namespace;
    public static string AppName 
        =Namespace.Substring(Namespace.LastIndexOf('.',Namespace.LastIndexOf('.') - 1) + 1);
}
```

this is the program found in Program.cs, look that it doesn't have a defined namespace, there are a bunch of functions defined as 'GetDefinedPorts'. I am following the Microsoft microservice implementation example https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Visual Studio 2022. It doesn't happen in 2019. They are also in the middle of converting the solution to dot net 6 so things may get a little more stable after that work is complete.